Uniqueness of solution of the operator equation $AXB=BXA$ on $B(H)$
Suppose we have Hermitian operators $A$ and $B$ in the infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$. I am interested in conditions under which the operator equation $AXB - BXA = 0$ has a unique Hermitian solution $X$ (i.e., $X = 0$).
Thanks for any ideas.

First of all $A$ and $B$ cannot commute as otherwise $X=I$ is a nonzero solution.

If $A=B$, which gives $AB=BA$, then any $X$ is a solution.

Besides no $A$ or $B$ can be invertible as if, for example $A$ is invertible then $X=A^{-1}$ is a solution.

Adding to Ryszard's comment, however, both $A$ and $B$ have to be injective: if there would exist non-zero $x\in{\rm ker}(A)$, then $xx^$ is a non-trivial solution (as $Ax=0$ together with $A=A^$ implies $x^A^=(Ax)^*=0$). Altogether this shows that both $A,B$ have to be injective, but neither can be surjective. But as Mohammed pointed out this cannot be sufficient in order for all solutions to be trivial.

Thanks guys for your comments.

@FrederikvomEnde Nice observation. By the way, congratulations on your soccer nationial team performance. It was a pleasure to watch the game, although my favorite sport is ground tennis.

I am unable to come up with an example of two injective selfadjoint operators for which the intersection of the ranges is trivial. Perhaps I am overlooking something easy.

Have you tried $T=A\oplus 0$ and $S=0\oplus B$, where $B$ are self-adjoint and injective?

There is a sufficient condition:  $A$ and $B$ are injective (that's a necessary condition due to the comment of @Frederik vom Ende)
and  ${\rm Im}\,A\cap {\rm Im}\, B=\{0\}.$  If $AXB=BXA$ then $AXB=0=BXA,$ as the intersection of the ranges is trivial. Hence $XB=0,$ because $A$ is injective. The range of  $B$ is dense, due to the injectivity of $B,$ therefore $X=0.$
Another necessary condition: for any $v\neq 0$ there holds $Av\neq Bv.$ Indeed, assume by contradiction that $Av=Bv.$ then for $Xx=\langle x, v\rangle v$ we have
$$AXBx=\langle Bx,v\rangle Av=\langle x,Bv\rangle Av \\ =\langle x,Av\rangle Bv=\langle Ax,v\rangle Bv=BXAx$$
